# RegistryKey.GetSubKeyNames throws IOException

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, registry, ioexception

When using [RegistryKey.GetSubKeyNames](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey.getsubkeynames.aspx), an IOExeption is thrown:

> "No more data is available"

Here is the relevant code:

```
string subKey = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-18\Products";
RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey( subKey );
string[] keys = key.GetSubKeyNames(); // throws IOException here
```

**Specs**

- Win7 x64
- VS 2010 SP1
- .NET 3.5

The exception is thrown when using a build type of "Any CPU"; when using a build type of "x86" the code executes as expected, but reads the keys from the "Wow6432Node" instead of the SubKey path named in the defined `subKey` string variable above.

**The question is**: how can I read all the SubKeys in the `subKey` path defined above on a 64-bit system (not the Wow6432Node)?

Of note: When I run the same code on another 64-bit system, the code executes without error. I'm almost inclined to think I may have a corrupted registry key somewhere? If so, any ideas on how I can find the corrupt key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass appropriate `RegistryView` to `RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey()`.

For example:

```
RegistryKey tempRegKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64).OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server");
```

Comment: `OpenBaseKey` appears to be a 4.0 method. I should have stated .NET 3.5. However, I did run a test under 4.0 using `OpenBaseKey` and the same exception occurred of "no more data is available". What's odd, is that I can get a count of the keys; but not an enumeration of the key names.

Comment: I'm a full admin on the system. I did try to reset all permissions on the SubKey and have child keys inherit the permissions, but that failed with an error of something like "not all keys could be updated". There are 200+ SubKeys and having to manually check each one's permission is going to be a PITA. I've reset about a 1/10th of them by hand... its slow going.

Comment: I was not able to figure out why the subkeys were not able to be read. In the end, I had to conclude that my registry was corrupted. While @Alistad's answer did not provide the solution, I've accepted it as it was the only answer posted.